# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited self._run_job(job)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Trying to send an embed at a set time only on weekdays, I can use asyncio sleep to run everyday (including weekends) but I want to skip Saturday and Sunday. Ive now imported schedule and get the error

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  self._run_job(job)
```

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord import Embed
import asyncio
import schedule
import time
import aiohttp
import tracemalloc


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='..')

@client.command()
async def startpoll(ctx): #command name
#scheduler
    
        #get channel
        channel = client.get_channel(1039973136361345034)
        # @everyone
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
            message = await ctx.send(f'{ctx.guild.default_role}')
        # embed
        description = []
        embed = discord.Embed(title='**Daily Market Prediction**', description='<:Green:865709217678360636> **Bullish**\n\n<:Red:865709217980350464> **Bearish**', colour=6398207)
            
        react_message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await react_message.add_reaction('<:Green:865709217678360636>')
        await react_message.add_reaction('<:Red:865709217980350464>')

        while True:
            schedule.every().thursday.at('23:18').do(startpoll)
    
       
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Was expecting a post while testing at 23:18, but once this time is hit the error appears

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the schedule library but you should have a look into the [tasks extension of discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html), it can handle tasks at specific times for you.

But it‘s very simple, the library you‘re using cannot handle async functions, what a command in fact is...

Just use said extension. It‘s build in in discord.py and works perfectly fine with async code and put your. If you need further help with it, just ask ;-)